# Are there alternatives to Stagbar antler chews?

Tags: dogs, treats

Our dogs absolutely love these [Stagbar dog chews](http://www.puredog.co.uk/our-products/stagbar-antler-dog-chews/). They are the only treat I can find which keeps our dogs interested and is durable enough to last more than a few hours (the large ones usually last a few weeks). One of our two dogs also has severe trouble digesting normal bones/rawhide treats but these don't seem to have any adverse effects at all.

However recently, our local pet store has stopped stocking them. I was wondering if there was maybe something wrong with them that they've stopped selling them? They also seem to be very low on stock on Amazon.

Are there any similar alternatives?

**edit:** Took Ashley's advice and e-mailed the supplier - they replied with the following:

> Due to the popularity of the product we saw a huge spike in demand
>   Sept/Oct last year. As a result we ran the whole European stock out
>   before the new shed antler arrives in April.   As you know it’s a
>   natural product and we can’t just produce as much as we want.   We
>   hope to have Pets at home restocked in March and have sourced some
>   antler from the Southern hemisphere but it takes a long time to get
>   here and get all the correct government paperwork in place.   So
>   hopefully during March you should see a return to normal, but in the
>   meantime if you do require some we are keeping a small supply

Which is good news and alleviates any concerns I had about the product, but I'd still like to know if there are any similar alternatives, given the apparent supply shortage.

Comment: You can usually check with the manufacturer, they often list contact info on packaging. They might be able to tell you where to find them, or any reason why there might be issues with availability.

Comment: Since you checked the supplier regarding availability, maybe they know of a good alternative to use in the meantime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have an aggressive chewer as well and I have found a few chews that she won't destroy too quickly:

- **Himalayan Chews :** A lot of pet stores sell these in several different sizes depending on the dog's size. These are yak-milk products, but are cured so they do not cause the intolerance issues that cheese normally does for dogs. They are very hard, and it takes our dog weeks to go through one.
- **Petedge :** If you are looking for antlers, try [Petedge](http://www.petedge.com). I buy from them often for my business, and I get antlers for our dog there when I need them.
- **Marrow bones from the butcher :** Great for keeping dogs busy for awhile. Once they get all the marrow out, they still have the bone to gnaw at. Our dog loves them, but you do have to be careful about letting them have these on carpet. They can be messy.